# Electrons flow difference between circuit and electroplating process by considering battery's positive and negative side

Tags: electrons

Electrons flow  from the negative end to the positive end of a battery (via a circuit) but in electroplating process electrons flow from the battery's positive end  to the battery's negative end. Why this happens ?
Here I want to know about the electrons flow difference in battery's positive side  to the battery's negative side between circuit and electroplating system.
[image]

Here in the first figure by considering battery's positive and negative side electrons flow from positive side to the negative side.

[image]

But in this second figure by considering battery's positive and negative side electrons flow is opposite from the first figure.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] and visit the [help] for any questions on how this site works. I frankly fail to understand your question, because the electrons are still flowing from negative to positive. Remember that *cathode* and *anode* are names for the electrodes of *reduction* and *oxidation* respectively and *do not* reflect a charge.

Comment: Does the duplicate not answer your question? If so, please explain why. If you have a new question, your chances are better if you post it using the 'ask question' button.